# How to change tomcat 8 port

Tags: configuration, tomcat

I am trying to change the Tomcat's port to 80 in Ubuntu 14.04 through this configuration [conf/server.xml]:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

to:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

And I am receiving this error:

```
13-Oct-2015 18:09:10.626 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

What I am doing wrong? Or what is missing?

Thanks...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To run Tomcat on a port below 1024 in Ubuntu/Unix, the service needs root privileges. And that you do not want.

Use a port redirection via `iptables`

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: Thank you very much A.B. What are my options then?

Comment: Improved my answer.

Comment: When redirecting using iptables, whenever I send a request to my ip, it automatically adds :8080, is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

Start tomcat services using authbind this will allow user to start ports less than 1024 we do not need to redirect or iptables.

> sudo apt-get install authbind -y

To install Authbind software

> sudo chmod -R 755 /etc/authbind

group should be user group.

> sudo chown -Rh root:group /etc/authbind

After that run the below commands

> cd /etc/authbind/byuid

As an example lets imagne user id is 2000 you can use your user id number

> sudo echo '0.0.0.0/0:1,1023' > 2000

That file should be own by user and group.

sudo chown : 2000

sudo chmod 700 2000

Add the below line in tomcat startup file $CATALINA_BASE/startup.sh

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

For Starting tomcat using Authbind service startup.sh

Comment the below line

```
#$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

Add This End as the end of the file

```
AUTHBIND_COMMAND="/usr/bin/authbind --deep /bin/bash -c " 

$AUTHBIND_COMMAND $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

now you should be able to start tomcat services as user with less that 1024 ports.

Comment: echo '0.0.0.0/0:1,1023' > userName
results permission denied

Comment: please be root or use sudo

Comment: I used sudo but same error

Comment: become root and try