# Listening on port 80 in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, java, iptables

I have an Ubuntu 15.04 system with a Java webserver listening on port 3000. Iptables prerouting is setup like this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

I've also removed apache2 packages from the system with:

```
apt-get remove apache2
```

However, now i don't get any process listening on port 80 in the system:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      259/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4841/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      455/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      256/systemd-resolve
```

As a consequence the pages are not accessible from the browser. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
For now i've ended up configuring Apache with `proxy` and `proxy_http` modules, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

</VirtualHost>
```

What is weird is that on a similarly configured machine running Ubuntu 14.04 running Apache in order to have some process listening on port 80 was not necessary. On these machines, `netstat` also would show no processes listening on port 80, yet HTTP requests were somehow forwarded to Java server listening on port 3000. Hmmm.

Comment: According to http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/, i see a difference on the order of params that it may make a difference, `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING` instead of `iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat`. You can check your NAT rules with `iptables -t nat -L -n -v`, also, did you save it with `iptables-save`?

Comment: @bistoco - thanks for your comment, order was fine. I've used `wget` on port 3000, and the responses were ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing *is* listening on port 80 anymore. That iptables command just forwards requests to port 80 on an external network to port 3000 locally.

But the service is still only listening on port 3000, and nothing else is (apparently) listening on port 80, which is what is being reported by your system.

My guess is that you are testing this locally (i.e., with a browser on the same machine as the service). If this is the case, and localhost:3000 reaches the service, then the iptables rule is not being reached because the request is not coming on an external network (or some other iptables related reason -- I am assuming here that your rules are sound and working, but you should check this.)

Possible solutions:

1. Ensure that all traffic is going through this iptables rule, or create multiple rules so traffic from all sources for port 80 is redirected to 3000.
2. Change the service so it binds to port 80, and remove the iptables forwarding stuff.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Upvoting it, as it gave some important clues. However, other VMs that i've configured earlier running Ubuntu 14.04 also do not have anything listening on port 80, yet work properly. `wget localhost:3000` yields correct response, but `wget localhost:80` gives `Address family not supported by protocol`. Maybe it's related to IPv4 vs IPv6. For now i've ended up running Apache with proxy directives redirecting to the java server at port 3000.

Comment: The wget traffic that handles port 80 redirections is not being redirected by the firewall route, or is not falling back to IPv4, or the redirection is not working, or the redirection is doing something wrong. The VMs have a different routing or redirection setup. You can use the `--inet4-only` option to wget to properly test localhost redirections (or just use a web browser). wget not falling back to IPv4 is reported as a bug, and the later version of Ubuntu might have a buggy version of wget.

Comment: Also, note that you may have created a situation where some traffic is being redirected via an HTTP proxy, and other traffic is redirected via TCP firewall rewrites. This may cause problems down the road.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the firewall rule after migrating to Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you use authbind to start tomcats then we do not need iptables or any redirecting rules softwares or apache
hope this link will be help full.

https://askubuntu.com/a/685306/377678